# How can I auto generate copyright above classes when created in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I did this a while ago and have since then needed to re install my PC.
I want to when I create a new class auto generate som text that should be displayed as a Java doc comment above my class like this:

```
/**
 * Created by Name <br>
 * Date: ${DATE} <br>
 * Time: ${TIME} <br>
 * Project: ${PROJECT_NAME} <br>
 */
public class Test {
    code here...
}
```

I think this is the right code for auto generate date and time etc but that should also be autogenerated ofcourse to match the date and time.

Comment: is https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright-profiles.html#profile_page this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You may create the copyright profile here:

*Preferences | Editor | Copyright | Copyright Profiles*

… using the [Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity) templates as described in the documentation, [*Copyright Profile Page*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright-profiles.html#profile_page).

Then define the default copyright or the profile for scope here:

*Preferences | Editor | Copyright*

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with the official plugin
[**Copyright**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13114-copyright)

Comment: I found the way again. In Settings -> Editor -> Files and code templates. Go to includes and paste what I wanted and apply. Simple as that